# Show only dayView in MACalendarUI

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, nsdate

I am exploring this iOS 7 project - https://github.com/muhku/calendar-ui

Its a calendar view of day and week. I want to edit it to show only the day view in the whole 4" screen. I don't want tab bar controller or week view. Also I don't want to use NIBs.

I tried making the DayViewExampleController as rootViewController but that is crashing the app. On crash it gives the following error `-[UIView setAutoScrollToFirstEvent:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x94765b0` on the line `dayView.autoScrollToFirstEvent = YES;`

How can I go about it?

Comment: If it crash, what's the error message?

Comment: @Larme please check the question now. I edited with crash information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the custom class for view of DayViewExampleController,  to [image: MADayView].